# R - Importing multiple xlsx files with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, import, xlsx, assign

I'm having some trouble writing a function to read in multiple .xlsx files as separate data frames in R with a for loop. When I run the function nothing happens. No Errors, but no data frames are loaded into R either. When I take the assign piece out of the function and manually change the input from the for loop to an example the assign function works. Here is an example of the code:

```
library(readxl)
Load<-function(File_Path,Samp){
  setwd(File_Path)
  for (i in 1:length(Samp)){
    assign(paste("Sample_",Samp[i],sep = ""),read_excel(paste("Sample_",Samp[i],".xlsx",sep = "")))
  }
}
Load(File_Path = "~/Desktop/Test",Samp = "A") # Doesn't Work

#When this piece is taken out of the loop and the Sample ("A") replaced it works.
assign(paste("Sample_","A",sep = ""),read_excel(paste("Sample_","A",".xlsx",sep = ""))) # Does Work
```

In reality there is a long list of samples to load and want to do so by assigning a list to "Samp" such as c("A","C","D"). Thanks up front for any assistance.

Comment: The issue is that `assign` uses the environment that it is called in so using it in a function assigns it in the function's environment not the global environment. Also the function doesn't return anything. You should consider a different approach, but if you really want to use `assign` see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem by adding `inherits=TRUE` to `assign`